How can I get the prices of the previous days at the end of the exchange in pinescript?
I tried to use the following code line to get the average of the previous 365 days, but it returns the lasts 365 bar prices:
ta.sma(close, 365)
How can I get the prices of the previous days at the end of the exchange in pinescript?
I tried to use close, but it gets the price of the last bar. But what I want is the last price at the end of each of the 365 days.

Try request.security
closeD = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close)
plot(closeD)

